# Java - Anyway to tell if a directory is marked as the sources root?

Tags: java, directory, src

In Java, is there any way to tell if a directory has been marked as the sources root? I know calling it "src" is the standard, but I'm sure there's no guarantee that this will always be the case.

Comment: No but you can make a method just to search it for if the files are `.java` and say it is then.

Comment: "source folders" are an IDE feature. It informs the IDE of which folders contains files to be compiled, adding them to the buildpath. Without an IDE, it's up to the developer to explicitly state the buildpath. It simply helps the developer determine which folders are already specified on the buildpath. Check out [What is the difference between a source folder and a (normal) folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12736632/what-is-the-difference-between-a-source-folder-and-a-normal-folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do this.  The Java compiler doesn't put information about where it found the source files into its output.  So when you're running an application consisting of a bunch of class files, the Java runtime can't know where the source files are.