# Duplicate folders confusion

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Im working with a new Eclipse Maven Java project and there seems to be 2 duplicate folders. One src/main/java and one src folder, which contains a main folder. I am confused where do I need to make my new java files? Note: Archetype definitions have not explained the difference between these two.

[image]

Comment: In the Source folder (with the little square) `src/main/java`. The `src/main` is not a source folder (no decorator).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a source folder and a (normal) folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12736632/what-is-the-difference-between-a-source-folder-and-a-normal-folder)

Comment: what is the difference between the two

Comment: The `src/main` isn't used for compilation, the `src/main/java` with the decorate is. Look at the properties for `myprojectname` and under the Source tab in `Java Build Path` you'll see the source folders. Maven has the convention of `src/main/java`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide src folder from eclipse project explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14437227/how-to-hide-src-folder-from-eclipse-project-explorer)

Answer (score 0):

The eclipse view can be confusing. If you go through the project on the hard disk, you see that there are no duplicate folders.

Create your source code files in `src/main/java´ and everything will be all right.