# can't set breakpoints on eclipse, it adds bookmarks

Tags: eclipse, breakpoints

basically it is what the title says. i'm using the latest version of eclipse, on fedora. whenever i try to set a breakpoint it prompts me with:

Add bookmark : [insert code]

ive searched for solutions on the web

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oU5KD.png)

usually, in windows(recently switched) i would double click lets say next to line 34, for example, and it would add a breakpoint. now it prompts me to add a bookmark

Comment: Is this while editing a Java source file in a project in the workspace?

Comment: @nitind yes it is, on a regular java project

Comment: Can you describe exactly what you are doing to attempt to create a bookmark?

Comment: @DavidM.Karr im attempting to toggle a breakpoint, by double-clicking, as i would normally, but it prompts me to create a bookmark

Comment: @moita , not sure why that isn't working. Try right-clicking in the margin instead and select the breakpoint option.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr can't, only have these options https://imgur.com/a/1o20r5t

Comment: Oh, I get it. It doesn't think it's a Java source file. Is this file in a directory rooted by one of the source directory entries in the project?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you are saying: https://imgur.com/a/zuzPJPG)

Comment: It does not. If you don't know about source folders in Eclipse, you won't be able to do much with it. Try reading some documentation. The following mentions this subject: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12736632/what-is-the-difference-between-a-source-folder-and-a-normal-folder .

Comment: so should i move my files elsewhere?